# Light weight one axis hinge name/recommendation

Tags: control, robotic-arm, design, mechanism, motion

I'm attempting to build a crow that can stay upright even when its perch tilts.  For that I need to have some single axis hinges (not u-joints).  I'm using 3mm rod for my internal supports and am hoping to find some light weight hinges that are sized appropriately and can take a lot of duty cycles and still remain fairly friction free.

1. I've included an image of one I'm thinking of but I can't for the life of me find the name of it.  Does anyone knew the name so I can find one on amazon or McMaster Carr?  (I could make them myself, but time is short and I have plenty of others things to do first)
2. Is there a better choice?

[image: Hinge]

[image: Main Body]

Comment: if I had to name it, I'd call it `tube hinge`   ....... `Is there a better choice?` cannot be answered  because you did not say how you are using the hinge

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=balancing+fork&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: Fair Nuff.  I'm using the hinges on opposing platforms connecting by the 3mm rod to keep them separate.  There will a mechanism that keeps the top platform (that will hold the head) parallel to the bottom platform that the feet are attached to.  I'll attempt to add another image to help clarify.

Comment: Also I was able to find tube hinges. (thank you) Would there be a better hinge for this application?  My concern is whether repeated action (this could be in play for a long while) would wear down these hinges faster than a better option.

Comment: rotate the hinges 90 degrees on vertical axis... that will keep the platforms parallel

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.mcmaster.com/product/98010A290) is the kind of hinge you're looking for on McMaster, and it takes [8-32 threaded rod](https://www.mcmaster.com/products/threaded-rods/system-of-measurement%7Einch/thread-size%7E8-32), but I'm not understanding how the upper platform doesn't just fall over in your drawing, so I can't comment on alternatives.

Comment: Perfect and thank you.. Their mechanism to tilt it will be fairly complex and will also keep the platforms parallel.  (I've already prototyped it so it <should> work). Main concern on this was how well the hinges would wear over time, but since the hinges are threaded, they are easy enough to replace down the road if I get into trouble.